# Activate a preloader only when a button was click in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a button here And a code for preloader:

Now using JavaScript, I don't want this to load when the page loaded first. Instead I want to load this preloader when I click on the submit button for about 2-3 seconds. So on my Javascript:

```js
submitBtn.addEventListener('ciick', () => {
      window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        document.querySelector('body').classList.add("loaded")
      });
```

```css
#loader-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#loader {
  background-image: url('https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/business-avatar-1/512/1_avatar-512.png');
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 120px;
  height: 119px;
  margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
  border-top-color: white;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  z-index: 1001;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" id="submit-btn">Submit</button>

<div id="loader-wrapper">
  <div id="loader"></div>
  <div class="loader-section section-left"></div>
  <div class="loader-section section-right"></div>
</div>
```

However, this one did not work. Instead, the loader loads forever and never stops when I load the page. How can I fix this issue and only attain the loading state when the button was click?

Comment: In order to not show it when the page loads, hide it initially. Like `display: none;` in your `#loader-wrapper` rule. When you want to show it, just set  `loaderDiv.style.display = "block"`. (btw, assigning an event listener like that inside a button's click listener is asking for trouble, in 99% of cases, all event listeners are assigned when the page loads, and prepared to act according to app state when the event is triggered)

Comment: `'ciick'` should be `'click'`, and your function is not closed (bracket). You probably have errors in your console because the script crashes at start.

Comment: can you give me an example using my code?

Comment: `submitBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.getElementById('loader-wrapper').classList.add('d-block');
    document.querySelector('body').classList.add('loaded');
});`

Tried this but did not work. I put display: none on `loader-wrapper` first